# Loop through mongodb Collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to push `ip1`, `ip2`, `ip3` fields of the following collection into the `ips` array of each document.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "540dc0e605c458b3e5481911",
    "valid_ip": "100.100.XXX.191",
    "ip1": "100.100.XXX.191",
    "ip2": "100.100.XXX.103",
    "ip3": "100.100.XXX.192",
    "ips": [ ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "540dc0e605c458b3e5481910",
    "valid_ip": "100.100.XXX.250",
    "ip1": "100.100.XXX.250",
    "ip2": "100.100.XXX.249",
    "ips": [ ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried to run this command in `mongo` but it didn't change anything.

```
db.servers.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function(e) {
    if (e.ip1) {
      e.ips.push(e.ip1);
      db.events.save(e);
    }
  }
);
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is fine. Are you trying to update in events collection or same collection i.e servers ?. To update the same collection -

```
db.servers.find().snapshot().forEach(
   function(e) {
    if (e.ip1) {
       e.ips.push(e.ip1);
       db.servers.save(e);
     }
   }
);
```